# iAD advertising is not shown in app store application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iad

iAD advertising is not shown in app store application. But everything is OK when I launch it with xCode and when I test in with Testflight.

My app appeared on app store on the 7th of January (3 days ago) and when I download it from App Store I don't see ads.

Here is the screen of my itunes settings (so I don't think that the problem is there):

[image]

May be I need to setup smth in itunesconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-> Actually Ads appeared after one day. I don't know, but this was the first time I used them on an app, so I received in iTunes Connect a message that iAds were activated after one day.

-> iAd may not be displayed on your device if there is no Ad available to display targeting your device and your type of application. Even if iAd is available, there may be no advertisers that chose to launch ads that corresponds to your app

-> Currently iAd is supported in some of the countries. Because of this it might be possible you are not able to see the ads.

Supported Countries,

```
iAd campaigns currently run in the U.S, Canada, Mexico, U.K., France, Germany, Italy, Spain, Australia, New Zealand, and Japan.  (as per Oct. 2013 )
```

Comment: I tested it in Russia, and I see http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203102 , so Russia is supported